# <a> Tag Not Working?

Tags: php, javascript, css, hyperlink

This may seem a basic question but my  is not currently working. I am not sure why this is happening, it may be the javascript, or that I have written the page in PHP or that I am using z-index, But I cannot solve it.

You can see the problem here:
http://www.maxrichardson.co.uk/home.php

The issue is on the yellow 'CV button' on the right:

The code I am using is:

```
#CV-Download    {
    position: fixed; 
    margin: 50px 0 10px 10px; 
    z-index: 888; 
    right:0; 
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background:url(images/cv.png);
    }

#CV-Download:hover  {
    background:url(images/cv-hover.png);
    z-index: 889; 
    }


<div id="CV-Download">
<a href"Max Richardson CV" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Side CV Button']);" title="My CV" rel="0" class="newWindow" >CV</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Older IEs wont play nice with attaching a `:hover` to an element other than an `<a>`. You'll probably have to do it with JS instead. Or abandon IE compat support - which while tempting is the lazy way out...

Comment: I want to keep this as friendly as possible on all browsers, what would the code be for this as javascript hover please?

Comment: In pure JS: `var cvDownload = document.getElementById('CV-Download'); cvDownload.onmouseover = function() { this.style.background = 'url(images/cv-hover.png)';  this.style.zIndex = 889; }; cvDownload.onmouseout = function() { this.style.background = 'url(images/cv.png)'; this.style.zIndex = 888; };`. Since this is pure JS and not inline on the HTML tags, you would need to run this code after the DOM is available - so place the code in a `<script>` tag in the body after the HTML you show or (better) put it inside `window.onload`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've missed the equals after the `href`

```
<a href"Max Richardson CV"
```

Should be

```
<a href="Max Richardson CV"
       ^
```

Comment: Ow Wow thats embracing, haha. cheers mate. This Thread should be removed lol.

Comment: Also, "Max Richardson CV" is not a valid href. (Well, technically it could be, but I'm not betting that it is in this case.)

Answer (score 5):

It needs to be

```
<a href="whatever">text</a>
```

You're missing the `=`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href"Max Richardson CV" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Side CV Button']);" title="My CV" rel="0" class="newWindow" >CV</a>
```

... is missing the '=' between href and Max. Also I suggest to make it
 `href='#' title='Max Richardson CV'`

Answer (score 2):

forgot = after href:

```
<div id="CV-Download">
<a href="Max Richardson CV" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Side CV Button']);" title="My CV" rel="0" class="newWindow" >CV</a>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `=` sign in the line

```
<a href"whatever">text</a>
```